# React-Admin ReferenceInput issues

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-admin

I am trying to reference category in my create and edit product page. Please find the code below:

```
const validateProduct = (values) => {
    const errors = {};
    if (!values.name) {
        errors.name = ['Product name is required'];
    }
    if (!values.category) {
        errors.category = ['Product category is required'];
    }
    return errors
};
export const ProductCreate = (props) => (
    <Create {...props}>
        <SimpleForm validate={validateProduct}>
            <TextInput source="name" />
            <ReferenceInput label="category" source="category._id" reference="categories">
                <SelectInput optionText="name" />
            </ReferenceInput>
            <TextInput source="price" />
            <LongTextInput source="description" />
            <TextInput source="image" />
        </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
);

const ProductTitle = ({ record }) => {
    return <span>Product {record ? `"${record.name}"` : ''}</span>;
};

export const ProductEdit = (props) => (
    <Edit title={<ProductTitle />} {...props}>
        <SimpleForm validate={validateProduct}>
            <DisabledInput source="id" />
            <TextInput source="name" />
            <ReferenceInput label="category" source="category._id" reference="categories">
                <SelectInput optionText="name" />
            </ReferenceInput>
            <TextInput source="price" />
            <LongTextInput source="description" />
            <TextInput source="image" />
        </SimpleForm>
    </Edit>
);
```

There are few issues with the ReferenceInput:

1. Validation does not work for ReferenceInput.
2. Existing category is not selected by default in the edit product page.

[image]

I want the category validation and category selection enabled in add/edit pages. How do I achieve that in React-Admin?

Thanks

Comment: I fixed the validation issue by using per input validation as mentioned in the docs. The code:
const required = (message = 'Required') =>
    value => value ? undefined : message;
and then using it:
<TextInput source="name" validate={required()} />
But record is not accessible inside <Edit> component, hence cant set defaultValue. Tried creating Custom component for <ReferenceInput/> but it didnt work as well.

Comment: Hello. I bumped into this same problem months and now i'm trying to fix this. Any new i'll be posting here

Comment: Hello again. i solved the problem! In my case the server was returning the id referenced in the source of the ReferenceInput as a string.Test returning the attribute used on the input as a numeric value and see if it works. I'm waiting for a feedback

Comment: @GabrielMarques, the id from mongodb is a string. I had given up using React-Admin, as i was not able to resolve this issue.